# Kerberos/LDAP : Kerberos Container create FAILED: No such object while creating realm 'KERBEROS.COM'

Tags: ldap, kerberos, openldap

I have to set up a Kerberos server with OpenLDAP backend.
I installed OpenLDAP, I installed Kerberos.
Now, I have to join the two. I use kdb5_ldap_util to do this.

```
root@server-kdc:~# sudo kdb5_ldap_util -D cn=Manager,dc=company,dc=local create -subtrees dc=company,dc=local -r KERBEROS.COM -s
Password for "cn=Manager,dc=company,dc=local":
Initializing database for realm 'KERBEROS.COM'
You will be prompted for the database Master Password.
It is important that you NOT FORGET this password.
Enter KDC database master key:
Re-enter KDC database master key to verify:

Kerberos container is missing. Creating now...
kdb5_ldap_util: Kerberos Container create FAILED: No such object while creating realm 'KERBEROS.COM'
```

Here is the log :

```
root@server-kdc:~# cat /var/log/syslog
.
.
.
May 26 15:34:59 server-kdc slapd[4601]: conn=1033 op=1 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=32 nentries=0 text=
May 26 15:34:59 server-kdc slapd[4601]: conn=1033 op=2 ADD dn="cn=Manager,dc=company,dc=local"
May 26 15:34:59 server-kdc slapd[4601]: conn=1033 op=2 RESULT tag=105 err=32 text=
May 26 15:34:59 server-kdc slapd[4601]: conn=1033 op=3 UNBIND
May 26 15:34:59 server-kdc slapd[4601]: conn=1033 fd=18 closed
May 26 15:34:59 server-kdc slapd[4601]: conn=1032 op=1 UNBIND
May 26 15:34:59 server-kdc slapd[4601]: conn=1032 fd=17 closed
May 26 15:34:59 server-kdc slapd[4601]: conn=1031 op=1 UNBIND
May 26 15:34:59 server-kdc slapd[4601]: conn=1031 fd=16 closed
May 26 15:34:59 server-kdc slapd[4601]: conn=1030 op=1 UNBIND
May 26 15:34:59 server-kdc slapd[4601]: conn=1030 fd=15 closed
May 26 15:34:59 server-kdc slapd[4601]: conn=1029 op=1 UNBIND
May 26 15:34:59 server-kdc slapd[4601]: conn=1029 fd=12 closed
root@server-kdc:~#
```

It would be cool if you could help me.
Thanks.

Comment: It looks like LDAP and Kerberos are not configured, not adjusted to themselves, because LDAP domain (in your case company.local) doesn't match realm (KERBEROS.COM). Realm must be domain written upercase. In Linux you must carefully configure all three components (LDAP, Kerberos and DNS). When you install Active Directory it's done by a wizard...

Comment: Thanks for your help.
I didn't understand that the realm and the LDAP domain must be the same. I'll test it.
In my case, the DNS must be company.com ?
I'm thinking about switching to Active Directory. Does it contains a Kerberos Server ? If yes, does it act the same way than a Kerberos/LDAP server ?

Comment: You'd need _kerberos._udp.YOUR.DOMAIN. entries, as described here: http://www.gnu.org/software/shishi/manual/html_node/Configuring-DNS-for-KDC.html.

Comment: Yes, Active Directory contains Kerberos server. It's called "Kerberos Key Distribution Center", you can find it in services.msc, run on Windows Server. Once you install it, it's ready to be used.

Comment: Thanks for your help ! I've followed this tuto : http://www.rjsystems.nl/en/2100-d6-kerberos-openldap-provider.php which was very usefull.